# So Apple A7 is “System on chip or” or “CPU”?

Tags: iphone

Very confused, in some websites, they have this line:

```
iPhone 5s

CPU: Apple A7
```

other websites saying that:

```
iPhone 5s
System-on-chip: Apple 7
CPU: 1.3 GHz 64bit dual core
```

other sources saying that

```
iPhone 5s
System-on-chip: Apple 7
CPU: 1.3 GHz 64bit dual core Apple 7
```

in Wiki, it said:

> The Apple A7 is a 64-bit system on a chip (SoC) designed by Apple Inc.
>   It first appeared in the iPhone 5S, which was introduced on September
>   10, 2013. Apple states that it is up to twice as fast and has up to
>   twice the graphics power compared to its predecessor, the Apple
>   A6. While not the first 64-bit ARM CPU, it is the first to
>   ship in a consumer smartphone or tablet computer.

There are 2 sentences:

```
The Apple A7 is a 64-bit system on a chip (SoC)
```

&

```
  While not the first 64-bit ARM CPU
```

Wiki also said `The A7 features an Apple-designed 64-bit 1.3–1.4 GHz ARMv8-A dual-core CPU, called Cyclone`

So System on chip is also CPU? very confused

Then other source compares System on chip and CPU, they said "CPU will not work without other around components" & "System on chip is the combination of CPU & other components into a single chip."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The A7 as the A4, A5 and the A6 are Systems on a chip.

On the chip there is the CPU (an ARMv8), the GPU (a Power VR), the IO controllers and the RAM.

Comment: seem ur answer is right, so ARMv8-A is faster than ARM Cortex A8 (in iPhone 4) & Cortext A9 in 4s?

Comment: ok, i got it ARM Cortext A8 & A9 use 32-bit ARM architecture such as ARMv7-A while the ARMv8 use 64-bit

Comment: Are you sure the SoCs Apple use have integrated memory? I'm quite sure they stack chips, rather than integrating it onto the same die.

Comment: Yes they are stacked (RAM above the CPU/GPU/IO) it's not the same die but the same chip !

Answer (score 1):

A *SOC* contains more elements than just the CPU (graphics capabilities, sound, IO controllers etc), but the CPU is by far the largest, most complex component within it.  A SOC can be referred to as the CPU, because that's where it is (the rest of the contents  of a SOC are more variable, but there *has* to be a CPU), but obviously not all CPU can be classified as a SOC.